# Loading Routes via JSON in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I am trying to load the routes from a JSON file, as i do not want to hard code them and load the routes lazily. 
Something like this:

```js
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
const routes = [
    { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module' },
    { path: ':item/shoes', loadChildren: 'app/shoes/shoes.module' },
    { path: ':item/watch', loadChildren: 'app/watch/watch.module' }
];
export default RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

I want to load the following routes from a JSON file.

```js
{ path: '', loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module' },
        { path: ':item/shoes', loadChildren: 'app/shoes/shoes.module' },
        { path: ':item/watch', loadChildren: 'app/watch/watch.module' }
```

I am reading the JSON file using a service which is injected in a component. How do i inject the service in the router to get the values? Or is there any other better way using which i can load the routes from JSON?

Comment: did u found solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, Router } from '@angular/router';

import * as AppRoutingJson  from "./app-routing.json";

import { HomeComponent } from "./main/content/pages/joomla/home/home.component";
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from "./main/content/pages/joomla/page-not-found/page-not-found.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component  : HomeComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ],
    entryComponents: [
        PageNotFoundComponent
    ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

    constructor( private router: Router ){

        this.prepareRoutes( AppRoutingJson );

    }

    prepareRoutes( routesJson: any ) {

        let routesArr = <Routes>[];

        routesArr = routesJson;

        routesArr.forEach( route => {

            routes.push( route );

        });

        routes.push(
            {
                "path"      : 'page-not-found',
                "component" : PageNotFoundComponent,
            },
            {
                "path"       : '**',
                "redirectTo" : 'page-not-found'
            }                           
        );

        this.router.resetConfig( routes );  

    }

}
```